# How can I remove the string element in a series in Python?

Tags: python, pandas, series

I got a series name `basepay` that contains both String and Numeric element. What I wanted to do is to calculate the mean of the numeric part. I've tried `basepay.mean()` and the kernel return `TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'float' and 'str'` So I tried to drop off the non-numeric part.
I used `mask = basepay.astype(str).str.isnumeric()` to create a mask. But all the elements in the returning series are `False`.

Shouldn't it return `True` when the element in the `basepay` is like `'1234.32'` ?

By the way, is there a faster way to deal with this problem ?

Comment: provide a sample of basepay

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it might be easiest to just use a try catch block inside the mask function
like

---

```
try:
    float(basepay)
catch:
    do something if it fails
```

Answer (score 0):

## The `.isnumeric()` method doesn't accept decimal characters.

[The documentation states](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=isnumeric#str.isnumeric):

> Return `True` if all characters in the string are numeric characters,
> and there is at least one character, `False` otherwise.

`.` is not clasified as a 'numeric character':

```
>>> '.'.isnumeric()
False
```

## What you want is `not .isalpha()`

[The documentation states](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=isalpha#str.isalpha):

> Return `True` if all characters in the string are alphabetic and there is at least one character, `False` otherwise.

So `not .isalpha()` will check if there are any alphabetical characters and will return True if there are non. In this case `.` is not counted as an alphabetical character.

Example:

```
>>> '.'.isalpha()
False
```

Therefore:

```
>>> not '1234.32'.isalpha()
True
```